# How to get query string without equal sign using SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, key-value, http-request-parameters

We know @RequestParam is a good way to get query parameters like "?name=Tom" for example:

```
www.example.com/?name=Tom
```

and you can use

```
@RequestParam(value="name") String name
```

to get the key "name".

But how to get the query string without equal sign such as:

```
www.example.com/?1+1
```

There is no key-value pair in this case and I can't find the answer from the internet because basically query string is used by key-value case.

Btw, the Framework has to be SpringBoot with Java, and also html for Thymeleaf.

Comment: Here is one of the alternative way how you can do this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281067/how-to-request-complete-query-string-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 2):

You can get it from HttpServletRequest.getQueryString(). In the controller method, the HttpServletRequest is injected by SpringMVC.

```
@RestController
class WhatEverController {

   @GetMapping("whatever")
   public void whatEver(HttpServletRequest request,
                        HttpServletResponse response {
       String queryString = request.getQueryString();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks the same with @oisleyen's answer. I will use HttpServletRequest

Answer (score 0):

Querystring from another source :

```
public static Map<String, String> getQueryMap(String query)  
{  
    String[] params = query.split("&");  
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();  
    for (String param : params)  
    {  String [] p=param.split("=");
        String name = p[0];  
      if(p.length>1)  {String value = p[1];  
        map.put(name, value);
      }  
    }  
    return map;  
}
```

You can use

```
Map params=getQueryMap(querystring);
 String id=(String)params.get("id");
 String anotherparam=(String)params.get("anotherparam");
```